# Using .match() for case insensitive words

Tags: javascript, jquery, match

Currently I need to match the user input with an existing value and I have used,

```
 return book.id.match(keyword);
```

Now I need to make the keyword match to case insensitive where Bookt and BOOkT should also match for example. I tried using a regex but it is not letting me pass the 'keyword' variable to the regex. Any idea how to do this simply?

Comment: `.match(new RegExp(keyword, 'i'))` assuming there are no special symbols in the `keyword`.

Comment: `book.id.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())`

Comment: how would you do it if you are using a string in the match function like so?
"Test".match("test")
i tried "Test".match("test",'i') and that didnt work for me.
is it possible to use the case insensitive modifier when matching a text string rather than a regex expression?

Answer (score 1):

You can use match with regex as parameters.

```
var string = "BoOkt";
var result = string.match(/bookt/i);

if (result){
    alert('match');
}
```

alternate version from using regex is `indexOf`. If you have contain regex metacharacters from your user input and using `match` will be another problem for you.

```
var match = 'awesome';
var string = 'stackoverflow is AweSoMe place';

if (string.toLowerCase().indexOf(match) != -1){
    alert('match')
}
```

Comment: Note that the OP's code doesn't show any context; if the array returned by `.match()` is used for something then switching to `.indexOf()` won't work.